# Regex for URL with multiple directories

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a specific format mixed with numbers, and text.  The numbers are dates that will vary.

**These should match:**

`/shop/2017/12/04/string-of-text/another-string-of-text`

`/shop/2017/12/04/string-of-text/another-string-of-text/`

**These should not:**

`/shop/2017/12/04/string-of-text/another-string-of-text/more-text`

`/shop/2017/12/04/string-of-text/`

`/shop/2017/12/04/string-of-text`

---

Is this even possible?

So far I've gotten this far, but it seems to match in some of the cases where it shouldn't:

`^/shop/(.*?)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$`

Comment: On what basis the first ones are accepted and the last ones aren't?

Comment: Using a regex builder like this http://regexr.com/ would probably help you.

Comment: So what you are saying is you want to make sure those string have `/shop/` and a year `/2017` with a valid month `/08/` and day `/25/` but also much have two strings attached at the end `/string-of-text/another-string-of-text/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` and pretty sure you don't want to put `.*` at the end, as that will match anything after the last `/` which will not be what you needed; Try this `/^\/shop\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(?:\/[^/]+){2}\/?$/`;

- `^\/shop` matches `/shop` at the beginning;
- `\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}` matches the `/year/month/day`;
- `(?:\/[^/]+){2}\/?$` matches another two blocks of texts with an optional `/` at the end;

```js
var samples = ["/shop/2017/12/04/string-of-text/another-string-of-text", 
               "/shop/2017/12/04/string-of-text/another-string-of-text/", 
               "/shop/2017/12/04/string-of-text/another-string-of-text/more-text", 
               "/shop/2017/12/04/string-of-text/", 
               "/shop/2017/12/04/string-of-text"]

console.log(
  samples.map(s => /^\/shop\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(?:\/[^/]+){2}\/?$/.test(s))
);
```